# React Styled Components stripped out from production build

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I use Styled Components as CSS alternative for my React App. In development everything works fine (first screenshot), but when I run a production build (`npm build`), styles within style tags are stripped out (second screenshot). As a result, there're no styles in the production build.

[image: development]

[image: production]

Here is the production version: http://projects.loratadin.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/weather-app/

Here is the source code: https://github.com/Loratadin/weather-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue and it looks like when the application is in production, it can't select html elements within a styled component (the styles don't apply to the element). Instead, you'll need to create additional stylized components for `input` and `button`.

**Working example**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Weather-App

I refactored your application to simplify its structure. Please read the `README` for instructions on how to run it in development and in production (DO NOT use the above repository for production, as it's highly unnecessary to have an `express` backend -- I only did this so that you can run a local production build).

**What I changed**:

- Moved any `styled` components to the `components` folder for modularity
- Any sort of global stylization was put into a `styles` folder
- Moved `assets` to `images` and imported them into the `styled` component that needed them (eliminating the need to use `require('../path/to/image')`)
- Simplified the `App.js` file. Children are controlled by `state` and class `methods`. Most importantly, turned your `form` into a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), fixed the `getWeather` method to: Not allow an empty submission, if the `AJAX` calls fails, it'll `catch` the error (instead of breaking your app), and reset the form inputs on successful submission.
- Added `prop-types` to ensure `props` were consistent in declaration (string remains a string, number remains a number, and so on).

Comment: Thank you, Matt, for working on it and solving the problem, I learned a lot from your answer. Appreciate your time!

Comment: I dug a bit deeper and it looks like it wasn't integrated in v3.x (you're using v3.3.2). If you update to v4.1.1, it works as expected. Working example: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Styled-Components-Example (although, I'd still recommend reuseable styled-components or at the very least a specified className selectors over html element selectors: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting -- see 3rd example)

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue with empty style tags in production. I'm using a headless browser for server-side rendering and this issue caused the server-side rendered pages to appear with no styles before JS assets are loaded.

After a lot of searching around, I finally found out the reason. The Styled Components library uses something called the "Speedy mode" to inject styles on production. This makes the styles bypass the DOM` and be injected directly inside the CSSOM, thus, appearing in the inspector, but totally invisible on the DOM.

Fortunately, Styled Components 4.1.0 came with a fix for this issue! Now you can set a global variable called `SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY` to `true` in order to disable the `Speedy mode` and get the styles to appear on Production as well. Keep in mind that you should do it at the very beginning of your application's entry file, before importing any styled component, otherwise it will not work.

The way I did it is by creating a new file called `globals.js` that contains `global.SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY = true`
 and importing it as the very first thing in my `index.js`.

Reference: https://www.styled-components.com/releases#v4.1.0

Comment: Do you have any idea how we can disable Speedy mode in Create-React-App , because I did try your solution and seem the Speedy mode still active and not working .

Comment: @AJ- I use cra and you just need to create a .env file in your root and add
REACT_APP_SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY=true

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mate! For those who hit this, I found this really useful: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v410---2018-11-12

Comment: Mad that this isn't clearly documented in the official docs!

Comment: seems like the wrong advice IMO. you are disabling a major optimization to cover an edge case. best to figure out for styled components to recognize the style is needed. at least that's what i'm trying to do.. in my case style names are dynamic, and i think that is why they are being removed

Answer (score 5):

For the Create React App folks out there you can add a .env file in your root and add:

```
REACT_APP_SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY=true
```