# How to show full content of <style> element in devTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

When I am inspecting elements there are styles applied which are generated by webpack dev server and pasted in `<style>` elements. But when I try to inspect how those styles look like I am getting just partial content of that element.

How could I see the whole content?

I tried to find it in "view page source", but those style elements are added dynamically so they are not present in page source.

[image]

Comment: Someone should open a bug report and suggest them to use CodeMirror in contenteditable mode so it'll be able to edit large texts without problems.

Comment: For the similar problem of a `<style>` tag that appears *empty* in Dev Tools but is clearly applying invisible rules, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218279/where-are-my-css-classes-in-a-production-release-of-styled-componets - and its solution (accessing hidden CSSOM properties e.g. `$0.sheet.cssRules`) might also help here.

Comment: This works for me: Right click to element -> Copy -> Copy element. Not sure if this is due to Chrome update or not

Answer (score 3):

Only option I found so far is to click on style element, so it is selected. In console, let print content to console `$0.innerHTML`. `$0` is reference to latest marked html element in Elements tab.

Comment: Even that cuts off at a certain point (after pressing "load full content").. Any solution for that?

Comment: It was enough for me, I do not have any other solution yet. Please share when you find some, thanks :)

Comment: Nowadays there is "copy" and "show more" options at the bottom of console output... I have got whole content by using "copy" and pasting into IDE :)

Comment: @Luckylooke nope, Copy only copies the shown part including the three dots that replace the cut off content.

Comment: Still didn't find good solution, today I wanted to copy whole content of script tag, none of so far mentioned solutions did the thing. 

BUT I was lucky as the script was in page source (not added dynamically later). So I find him in "View Page Source". Actually it was "View Iframe Source" because it was in iframe, thanks God I had access to this. IMHO, iframe support is very week in devTools in general.

Answer (score 0):

Store style element as a global variable, then assign it innerHTML to a variable and show it in console. I was able to copy full 25kB contents of style tag

[image to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRWJ6.png)

Comment: didn't help :/ stil truncated by `...`